# Perl join function

Tags: perl

I'm having trouble using the join() in perl. I want to join a single column to the last column in each line in an array (tab delimited). For example (assume tab delimited):

```
@array = 

blue black grey
red orange pink

@add = 

hello
goodbye

desired output = 

blue black grey hello
red orange pink goodbye
```

The code I have is:

```
foreach my $line (@array) {
    my $line2 = join ("\t", $line, $add[$1]);
    print $line2;
    $i++;
}
```

However, what I get is:

```
blue black grey
hellored orange pink
```

I seem to be appending the first entry of @add (hello) to BEFORE the second line of where i want it to be. Any ideas?!

This may help:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (@array) {
    print $line;
    $i++;
}
```

output:

```
blue black grey
red orange pink
```

So my array is fine. If I print out $add[$1]:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (@array) {
       print $add[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Output: `hellogoodbye`

Hope that helps.
I'm sure it's something simple. I thought maybe a chomp issue, but no luck.
E

Comment: `$line` probably has a new line symbol at the end. Use `chomp $line` to remove it

Comment: Your code has a bunch of syntax errors in it, and you pseudo-code for the array creation isn't entirely clear. Try providing a [mcve].

Comment: @UjinT34 Sadly I had tried that and it doesn't work!

Comment: @quentin Please can you be more specific? I'm already simplifying things as I have data I can't share.

Comment: If you try to run it, then perl will tell you what the errors are.

Comment: (And never write programs without `use strict; use warnings;` - they catch all sorts of issues)

Comment: @quentin of course, already at top of code! My code is simplified for you and the arrays are printed for your convenience to save sending the rest of the code - shows you only the necessary bits.

This may help:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (@array) {
    print $line;
```

output: 
```
blue black grey
red orange pink
```

So my array is fine. If I print out $add[$1]:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (@array) {
       print $add[$i];
 $i++;
}

Output: 

```
hellogoodbye
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is why you should provide a [mcve] and not a snippet of code from the middle of the program with errors in it.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, have done. I didn't know you couldn't edit a comment in the same way - not clear from the guidance. Not everyone is an expert in stackoverflow :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of `@array` end in line feeds. Use `chomp` to remove them.

You probably have something like

```
my @array = <>;
```

Change that to

```
chomp( my @array = <> );
```

Don't forget to add a line feed when you output! (Or use `say` instead of `print`.)

Comment: worked like a charm! I tried chomp (my @array) before and it didn't work. I guess I needed the <> ??!

Comment: `chomp( my @array = <> );` is just short for `my @array = <>; chomp(@array);`

Comment: I presume you must preface with `my @array = <>;` prior to using `chomp(@array);`? I just tried `chomp(@array);` which hadn't worked.

Comment: No, I took a guess as to how you populated the array. I assumed you had used `my @array = <>;` to populate the array. No matter how you populated the array, `chomp(@array)` will remove the trailing line feed from each element.